# How to prevent break in div with float right? (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have the following HTML. And the text (tidbit) on the right keeps dropping off to the next line. This is in chrome. Is there a way to keep what is inside of the pull-right div together in one line? here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4634/).

```
<div class="container" style="width:500px;>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <span class="add-on">This can be quite long</span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input class="input-mini" name="Amount" type="number" />
            <button type="button" class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Add</button>
            <div style="text-align:right; width:40px;">tidbit</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

Comment: I found the `min-width` CSS attribute to be useful per this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709418/how-to-avoid-text-wrapping-in-a-td-with-text-and-a-right-floated-label).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perhaps add pull-left and pull-right inside the pull-right parent container

```
<div class="container" style="width:500px;">
    <div class="controls controls-row"> <span class="add-on">This can be quite long</span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <input class="input-mini" name="Amount" type="number" />
                <button type="button" class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right" style="text-align:right; width:40px;">tidbit</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/MgcDU/4635/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with two corrections:

1. Set `display: inline-block` in the "tidbit" div.
2. Set `white-space: nowrap` to the `pull-right` container.

```
<div class="container" style="width:500px;>
            <div class="controls controls-row">
            <span class="add-on">This can be quite long</span>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <input class="input-mini" name="Amount" type="number" />
                <button type="button" class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Add</button>
                <div style="text-align:right; width:40px; display: inline-block;">tidbit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</diV>
```

```
.pull-right{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bCfLZ/)

Comment: why does the text align vertically to the bottom. Is there a way to align to center? This does work as well but that vertical alignment is a problem for me.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez I'm not really getting, what you mean, but probably you could adjust using `margin`/`padding` ...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div tag around tidbit and, if necessary, wrap the tidbit in a span - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4636/)

```
<div class="container" style="width:500px;>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <span class="add-on">This can be quite long</span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input class="input-mini" name="Amount" type="number" />
            <button type="button" class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px">Add</button>
            <span>tidbit</span><!--Move this the before or after the button-->
        </div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

Comment: OK, I should have been more explicit on my question. But I need the width otherwise I the random tidbits make the alignment be all out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

What is the combined width of div class pullright controls. It is exceeding 500px i think.

If width of these 3 exceeds 500px, tidbit text will move to next line. So control width