# Bootstrap table no new line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<h3>Mijn biedingen</h3>
        <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>nummerplaat</th>
            <th>Bod</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Datum bod</th>
            <th>Aankoopdatum</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                    <tr>
            <td>THOMAS</td>
            <td>&euro;    90 000,00</td>
            <td>open</td>
            <td>15/10/2014</td>
            <td>
                                        Niet beschikbaar
                                </td>
        </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my code, this is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vkc2mpu7z4yqgq/Screenshot%202014-10-15%2019.28.09.png?dl=0

How can I have the money TD on one line? This website is responsive but the the text becomes in two lines because of the spaces in the text.

Comment: You are using `table-responsive` incorrectly! See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E027

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you want to have the text in same line use CSS style

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

eg:

```
<span class="nowrap">Your text here</span>
```

In CSS style sheet

```
 .nowrap {
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

**Bootstrap way of doing it**

Since you already have bootstrap, no need of class definition, you can use class `text-nowrap`

Just try this in your td or if doesn't work try adding a `span` around your text and assign the `class`

eg:

```
<td class="text-nowrap"> Your text </td>
```

or

```
<td> <span class="text-nowrap">Your text </span></td>
```

You can also have it in the **table tag,** so that no need to add in each element

eg: `<table class="text-nowrap">  .... </table>`

More on this in Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-alignment) Check under *Alignment classes*

Bootstrap 4 documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)

Bootstrap 5 documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow)

Comment: @StijnHoste Glad to know it helped. Please accept the answer if you think so.

Comment: You can add the class definition to the parent div or table class to nowrap all the text inside, instead of every single text.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I hab to add it to every td, but it's fine. Thanks :)

Comment: I added it directly to the table class and worked like a charm.

Comment: This is still a solid solution for BS4

Answer (score 3):

**Bootstrap 4.**

Can be applied to an entire table as well if you don't need to support multiple long text:

```
<table class="table text-nowrap">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/439dg2k0/1/

Answer (score -1):

Use `&nbsp;` instead of space

Comment: This will solve the problem, but it requires changing the data that's presented.  Fixing it with style lets you present arbitrary data and present it consistently.